# Jenkins "Expected when conditional"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Why does Jenkins have issues with this?

I followed as it said in the docs here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when

```
when { 
    allOf {
        branch: 'master';
        triggeredBy 'TimerTrigger';
    }
}
```

It errors with:

```
[2020-08-07T08:51:36.217Z] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
[2020-08-07T08:51:36.217Z] WorkflowScript: 18: Expected a when condition @ line 18, column 29.
[2020-08-07T08:51:36.217Z]                        branch: 'master';
[2020-08-07T08:51:36.217Z]
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `:` from `branch: 'master';`